# How to make soft body (jello) objects or arrays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, softbody

I want to make objects with jello-like texture or softer. I've tried the [NVIDIA Flex](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/nvidia-flex-for-unity-1-0-beta-120425) free package but it is missing a lot of features and doesn't work that well. Can anyone either point me to better (free) packages for softbody or tutorials on how to make jello/viscous fluids.

For some background, I am fairly new to Unity, have very little experience in C#, and want to use Unity for movie animation not game dev. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using blender for this. Blender is a much better 3D modeling software. In it, it is much easier to make textures and animations. You can easily make soft body in blender (not a simulation, you have to sculpt it, but I think it is much easier). And I mean you should use blender to make your movie. It’s your choice, but I think blender is better for this.

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to make [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552448/how-do-i-make-a-softbody-jello-sphere-with-nvidia-flex-in-unity3d) threads, especially with only a day between posting. Your question is rather narrow scoped and does not show any code. I do not know many who have used this beta NVIDIA package, so the off chance someone who has sees it and knows exactly what your answer is would be slim. Try sharing more details about your setup/implementation. Your best bet is asking this on [their forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/).